# Convert Curl Command to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl, httpwebrequest, x509certificate2

I am trying to convert a Curl Command to C#, This is how the command looks

```
curl -E <partner>.crt --key <partner>.key https://APIDomain/returns/?wsdl -v --no-alpn
```

This will return a wsdl file, Now how can I convert this code to c#?
Note: API requires me to authenticate the call with a X509 certificate, That's why the `.crt` and `.key` files are used here.
I have tried to achieve the same by below code, But it throws an error

> fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to APIDomain/ (for #1) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   On Fiddler

```
 string host = @"https://APIDomain/returns/?wsdl";
            string certName = @"C:\Cert\mydomain.pfx";
            string password = @"xxxxxxxxx";

            try
            {
                X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certName, password);

                ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
                req.PreAuthenticate = true;
                req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                req.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string postData = "login-form-type=cert";
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

                Stream postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                postStream.Flush();
                postStream.Close();
                WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

                Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                }

                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

Comment: This isn't a query that returns a WSDL file. This is a GET request using certificate authentication that requests whatever that URL points to. You can use HttpClient.GetAsync after you configure certificate authentication

Comment: Where is the code you currently have, and what is wrong with it?:

Comment: @BugFinder I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code?

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("<partner>.crt", key));
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var result = client.GetAsync("https://APIDomain/returns/?wsdl").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'HttpClientHandler' does not contain a definition for 'SslProtocols' and no extension method 'SslProtocols' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClientHandler' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Do I need to add any reference?

Comment: using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

Above dependencies are required

Comment: @Athul did you try adding the following code in your request above?

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that the requests are on TLS1.2 by checking fiddler. And the server I am trying to use requires TLS 1.2

Comment: @Athul is Expect100Continue = true; a requirement? Did you try sending it as false?

Comment: Yes, Tried now, No luck :(

Comment: @Athul Did you compare both Curl and C# requests in Fiddler? Are both equal? And try sending one request with Fiddler completely closed.